# How to show sites under "My Sites" Menu in admin panel wordpress multisite?

Tags: multisite

When i add new multisite by visiting "My sites -> Network admin -> sites", the list of sites appear.

This list contains more than 10 sites. But when i hover to "My Site" Menu in admin panel top admin bar, there are few sites are showing.

I wanna list all site down here on hover. How to achieve this?
What is the correct way to add a new site? OR can i hide this list which is howing few sites on hover?

**More details:**

Hovering over My Sites Menu showing few sites.

[image]

Going to "Sites" sub menu brings all sites list.

[image]

Comment: The easy way is to remember to use the same email as when you made the multisite (the Super Admin)

Answer (score 7):

- **My Sites** contains all the sites that are added to you as a user.
- **Sites** contains all the sites in the network.

This can be confusing since you're logged in as a superadmin and therefor have access to both but it simply means that the sites that are **not** showing up in the dropdown are not actually under your control (but you can still control them because you're a SA).

Under **Sites** go to a specific site and go to the tab **Users**

Here you can add the users that have access to that site and if you add yourself to all of them, they will all show up under **My Sites**

Answer (score 0):

FYI... I had to clear my cookies to get this to work because I was logging in with my user credentials but Wordpress was cookie'ing me to the a different original super admin account.

I logged out, cleared cookies, then logged in my personal super admin account and all the sites showed up in the sites dropdown menu.